# Google Cloud Natural Language Example

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I have followed the getting started page closely.

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php

The example code has the following: *$projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';*

I fill in my project id taken from the json file and the Google console--e.g. "$projectID = 'myproject-197218'" and I always get a fatal error with "Permission Denied."

I have set the env variable, run composer to install the library. And, I created the Google json file. I am running the example in PHP code.

I am running the code on my local server (xampp).

Comment: I am using in the right ID; the one above was a made up one--the real one is sustained-node-197218.

What I get back is: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Comment: I figured out my problem. The Google Cloud json file was stored on my drive d:, when I moved it to the root of the c: drive and referenced it there, it worked fine.

Comment: I'm glad to know that you've been able to find the solution to your issue. Can you please publish the solution as answer in order to help everyone that are facing similar issues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. The Google Cloud json file was stored on my drive d:, so in the env variable I referenced it as 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS= d:\xampp\htdocs\googapi\mproj.json', it did not work; when I moved it to the root of the c: drive and referenced it there (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=c:proj.json), it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the ID of your project is that one? I'm working in Google Cloud and I cannot see this project ID in our database, but if I type "my-project-197218" with a "-" between "my" and "project" I am able to find one project. please, to make sure that this is your correct project ID, run this command in your Google Cloud Shell to get the default project ID:

```
gcloud config list --format 'value(core.project)' 2>/dev/null
```